# Preview photos on iPad which is connected to DSLR with Apple Camera Connection Kit

Tags: dslr, nikon-d80, ipad

I know that I can plug my DSLR camera into my iPad with the Apple Camera Connection Kit and it will allow me to import those photos, but I'm not looking to import the photos.

I'd like to just be able to preview the photos immediately and potentially browse through them. My goal is to set up my camera on a tripod with the iPad mounted next to is in a photo booth-ish setup. People can pose, trigger the camera, and then see their photo on the iPad automatically.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to include my actual question..

Does anyone know of an iOS app that will allow me to accomplish this? An app that will let me automatically preview images as they are snapped on the attached DSLR?

Comment: @Blrfl, on your proposed edit: you _can_ select which photos to transfer. It's just not designed to do that while shooting.

Comment: So you're looking for some level of basic *tethering*.

Comment: Yes, in a fashion, but not using one of the eye-fi SD cards. I'm just looking for a wired solution since I already have the camera connection kit.

Comment: Have a look at [ShutterSnitch](http://www.shuttersnitch.com/) - it supports wi-fi/eye-fi and FTP, at least. [Capture Pilot](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/capture-pilot/id404906435?mt=8) lets you preview on an iPad, but you'll need a laptop and the Capture One Pro software as well - the camera apparently connects to the laptop, and the iPad acts as a screen. [Photosmith](http://connect.dpreview.com/post/2693143833/ipad-3rd-generation-workflow?page=3) needs Lightroom. It can use the Apple Connection Kit, but it's not clear if it can do it in real time.

Comment: Something like CamRanger sounds close to what you're describing, but does require additional hardware. http://www.camranger.com/

Answer (score 2):

One year old article says

> Tethering to the iPad is a hot topic. Currently, you can’t tether directly to the iPad with a cable, not even with Apple’s iPad Camera Connection Kit. You can, however, tether wirelessly..

Source: [TetherTalk](http://tethertalk.com/2012/02/08/shooting-tethered-to-ipad-the-apps-that-get-you-there/)

Answer (score 2):

The [Canon EOS Remote](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/EOS_app) app performs a version of this. You do have to capture the image then click either on the preview thumbnail or go into image viewing to actually view the images. They do not appear automatically full screen after an image is shot.

It works on both iOS and Andorid, so you can use an iPad or an Android tablet. The app works very well actually and I use it to do nearly exactly what you are describing.

The app currently is only compatible with the Canon EOS 6D DSLR.